# gcc optimization: Increment on condition

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc, optimization

I've noticed that gcc12 does not optimize these two functions to the same code (with `-O3`):

```
int x = 0;

void f(bool a)
{
    if (a) {
        ++x;
    }
}

void f2(bool a)
{
    x += a;
}
```

Basically no transformation is done. That can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/1G3n4fxEK

Optimizing `f` to the code in `f2` seems to be trivial and no jump would be needed anymore. However, I'm curious if there's a reason why this is not done by gcc? Is it somehow still slower or something? I would assume it's never slower and sometimes faster, but I might be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Many compilers optimize well with `x +=  !!(condition);` the !! Gets optimized away

Comment: @technosaurus What is the purpose of the `!!` prefix since `a` is already a `bool`? Even if it would not be, wouldn't `(bool)(condition)` be semantically equivalent and possibly faster (in debug) or at least as fast (in release)? I never understood why people use this notation instead.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard the typedef for `bool` can be `int` in pre c99 code, so one could pass any integer value in a bool parameter - adding that number could yield a different result than adding !!parameter... casting to bool would be the same as casting to int on those systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a substitution would be incorrect in a scenario where one thread calls `f(1)` while another thread calls `f(0)`.  If `x` is never *actually* accessed outside the first thread, there would be no race condition in the code as written, but the substitution would create one.  If `x` is initially 1, nothing would prevent the code from being processed as:

1. thread 1: read x (yields 1)
2. thread 2: read x (yields 1)
3. thread 1: write 2
4. thread 2: write 1

This would cause `x` to be left holding the value 1 when thread 2 has just written the value `2`.  Worse than that, if the function was invoked within a context like:

```
x = 1;
f(1);
if (x != 1)
  launch_nuclear_missiles_if_x_is_1_and_otherwise_make_coffee();
```

a compiler might recognize that `x` will always equal 2 following the return from `f(1)`, and thus make the function call unconditional.

To be sure, such substitution would rarely cause problems in real-world situations, but the Standard explicitly forbids transformations that could create race conditions where none would exist in the source code as written.

Comment: Great answer. Do you know a way to specify to compilers that they can do such optimizations? My current solution so far was to copy the value in a temporary variable, to do the operation locally, and then to write back the result (causing the optimization to be possible since the value is written back in all cases so no threads are expected to change the value as it is UB). This solution does not always cause compilers to do the optimizations and the main problem is that it is very cumbersome to do on large code (it make the code also less readable).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Unfortunately, useful progress toward such things was effectively undermined around 2005 when the idea caught hold that rather than adding constructs to invite such transforms, it would be better to exploit the fact that the Standard imposes no requirements on how implementations behave in situations classified as "Undefined Behavior", and regard any programs that are incompatible with such treatment as "broken".

Comment: @JérômeRichard: At the time, even I thought such a concept might be interesting as a theoretical exercise, but unfortunately it seems to have almost completely displaced research into approaches that would be easier to implement, more effective, and safer.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: What makes the clang/gcc approach to optimization especially sad is that writing code to use only standard-defined behaviors will often yield code which is slower than what clang and gcc would be likely to produce from source code that exploits platform-specific behaviors over which the Standard waives jurisdiction, and such code could be made reliable if clang and gcc were slightly less aggressive.

Comment: -fallow-store-data-races seems related, but does not affect code generation for this program.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Such switches are a lot scarier than they appear, since there's no coherent abstraction model shared throughout the optimizer.  There are many situations where two optimizing transforms would each be useful if applied individually, but yield disastrous results when combined.  I rather doubt the people responsible for the transforms associated with that switch have systematically investigated all other transforms with which it might interact, and guarded against all such interactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would have hoped the compiler would have changed f2 to f.   Reading and writing memory *may* require slow transactions to acquire a copy of the memory location, and update other bus controllers about the state of that location (Invalid -> Shared -> Modified).
Jumping around an update based on a register value is quite cheap; especially with the efficacy of branch predictors.

Answer (score -2):

A much simpler reason why that optimization isn't done is because `bool` is nothing but an alias for `int`. Specifically, nothing stops you from passing an arbitrary integer to your function:

```
int v = 5;
f2(*(bool *)&v);

// x = 5 here
```

Comment: It turns out GCC does not consider `bool` to be just an alias of `int` since the generated code change with an `int` as parameter. Besides, GCC still does the optimization with `x += (a != false) ? 1 : 0;` (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kh4vehjvn)) so I think the answer of supercat is a better explanation so far. Indeed, all tested compilers (GCC, Clang, ICC) stop generating a branchless version when at least one branch does not store `x`.

Comment: `x += (a != false) ? 1 : 0` of course that works, gcc can actually verify the value of the boolean there.

Comment: `bool` is an alias for `_Bool`. And `bool` will become a keyword too as per C23. `_Bool` and `int` are not compatible types. `*(bool *)&v` is a strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior.

Comment: Here's a fun little example https://godbolt.org/z/fqzbMq14r

Comment: `The value is actually 5` -- I'm not sure what lesson you tried to impart on me, but it failed. The value of that "boolean" is indeed 5. Also let me tell you exactly how relevant it is today that C23 will get a proper boolean type: